# How can I get the Maximum of a column value in a SQL Server Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server. Can someone tell me how I can get the maximum value of a column and store this into a variable.  In my case the column is called `Release` and it is in the `Test` table.

I assume that I can do something like SELECT MAX(RELEASE) from Test but how do I put this into an integer variable that I can use later on in the procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @Result int

select @Result = max(release) from test

select @Result
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of a single row, single column result and put in the variable:

```
declare @Result int

set @Result = (select max(Release) from Test)
```

Or you can set the variable in the query:

```
declare @Result int

select @Result = max(Release)
from Test
```